# Time of DateTime C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am trying to compare 24 hour time format stored as a string to the current time as follows

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult _ProgOn()
    {
        int i = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        var onNow = db.Programs
         .Where(u => u.PrOk == true)
         .Where(u => u.DaId == i)
         .Where(u => u.TimeOn == dt.ToString("HH:mm")); 
        return PartialView(onNow);
```

But that seems not to be acceptable to Linq query.  I will be grateful if I am pointed to the right direction.

Comment: Try `ToShortTimeString()` instead

Comment: "that seems not to be acceptable to Linq query" is very vague. Do get any exceptions? compile errors? please specify. otherwise you will get downvoted quickly

Comment: what is the type of `TimeOn`?

Comment: Yes I  think it is obvious not been acceptable means it was generating compile errors because Linq was not accepting the conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass time string to Linq query:

```
    int i = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");

    var onNow = from u in db.Programs
                where u.PrOk &&
                      u.DaId == i &&
                      u.TimeOn == time
                select u;

    return PartialView(onNow);
```

Also you don't need to compare boolean value with true/false. And I think query syntax looks better here.

Answer (score 0):

Linq will only be able to use what it can translate.  Try doing the conversion of the `DateTime` to a `string` and then do the comparison:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult _ProgOn()
{
    string t =  dt.ToString("HH:mm");

    int i = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    var onNow = db.Programs
     .Where(u => u.PrOk == true)
     .Where(u => u.DaId == i)
     .Where(u => u.TimeOn == t); 
    return PartialView(onNow);
```